# Direct limit of the finite tensor product of algebras over a commutative ring A.

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

[image]

Can anybody give me an independent proof for the universal property of tensor product for the direct limit $B$ in the picture without using the argument that the tensor product of algebras over a commutative ring is the coproduct.

Comment: What, for you, is the universal property of the tensor product of an infinite family of $A$-algebras?

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate of your other question [Direct limit of arbitrary family of tensor products of A-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520041/direct-limit-of-arbitrary-family-of-tensor-products-of-a-algebras) - but I'll write an answer there.